# Moving elements in 2d array for c

Tags: c, arrays

So I have 2d array filled with random numbers .For example:

```
#define d 4

int main(void)
{
int a[d][d];
int primary[d], secondary[d];
size_t i, j;

srand(time(NULL));

/* fill array with random numbers */
for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < d; j++)
        a[i][j] = rand() % 100;

/* save diagonals */
for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
{
    primary[i] = a[i][i];
    secondary[i] = a[d - (i + 1)][i];
```

How to mirror horizontally diagonals?

For example:

```
1  0  0  2     

0  3  4  0

0  5  6  0

7  0  0  8
```

---

```
8  0  0  7

0  6  5  0

0  4  3  0

2  0  0  1
```

Task is to print main matrix and then print matrix with mirrored diagonals however i got no ideas how cycle for this should look like.

I thought about cycle for rotating matrix for 180 degrees however I will loose the positions of elements that are not included to the diagonals.

Or can i save diagonal and then reverse it somehow.
Here is code for matrix and diagonal what should i do now.

Hope for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of approaches is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   4

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N][N] =
    {
        { 1,  0,  0,  2 },     
        { 0,  3,  4,  0 },
        { 0,  5,  6,  0 },
        { 7,  0,  0,  8 }
    };      

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    { 
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    printf( "\n" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N * N / 2; i++ )
    {
        int tmp = a[i / N][i % N];
        a[i / N][i % N] = a[(N * N - i - 1) / N][(N * N - i - 1) % N];
        a[(N * N - i - 1) / N][(N * N - i - 1) % N] = tmp;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    { 
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 0 0 2 
0 3 4 0 
0 5 6 0 
7 0 0 8 

8 0 0 7 
0 6 5 0 
0 4 3 0 
2 0 0 1
```

The same can be written using pointers. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   4

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N][N] =
    {
        { 1,  0,  0,  2 },     
        { 0,  3,  4,  0 },
        { 0,  5,  6,  0 },
        { 7,  0,  0,  8 }
    };      

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    { 
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    printf( "\n" );

    for ( int *first = ( int * )a, *last = ( int * )a + N * N; 
          first < last; 
          ++first, --last )
    {
        int tmp = first[0];
        first[0] = last[-1];
        last[-1] = tmp;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    { 
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```